# Error trying to install & run Telescope / meteor

Tags: meteor, meteorite

I've tried everything under the sun to get Telescope to run, using these [instructions](http://www.telesc.pe/docs/installing-telescope/)

When I run **meteor** I get the following error

```
[[[[[ ~/Telescope ]]]]]

=> Started proxy.
=> Started MongoDB.     
=> Errors prevented startup:

While building the application:
node_modules/meteorite/node_modules/prompt/node_modules/winston/node_modules/pkginfo/docs/pkginfo.html:1: Can't set DOCTYPE here.  (Meteor sets <!DOCTYPE html> for you)
node_modules/meteorite/node_modules/ddp/node_modules/meteor-ejson/node_modules/underscore/index.html:1: Can't set DOCTYPE here.  (Meteor sets <!DOCTYPE html> for you)
node_modules/meteorite/node_modules/ddp/node_modules/node-srp/node_modules/underscore/index.html:1: Can't set DOCTYPE here.  (Meteor sets <!DOCTYPE html> for you)
node_modules/meteorite/node_modules/ddp/node_modules/faye-websocket/examples/sse.html:1: Can't set DOCTYPE here.  (Meteor sets <!DOCTYPE html> for you)
node_modules/meteorite/node_modules/ddp/node_modules/faye-websocket/examples/ws.html:1: Can't set DOCTYPE here.  (Meteor sets <!DOCTYPE html> for you)
node_modules/meteorite/node_modules/prompt/node_modules/pkginfo/docs/pkginfo.html:1: Can't set DOCTYPE here.  (Meteor sets <!DOCTYPE html> for you)
node_modules/meteorite/node_modules/prompt/docs/prompt.html:1: Can't set DOCTYPE here.  (Meteor sets <!DOCTYPE html> for you)
node_modules/meteorite/node_modules/colors/example.html:1: Can't set DOCTYPE here.  (Meteor sets <!DOCTYPE html> for you)
node_modules/meteorite/node_modules/underscore/index.html:1: Can't set DOCTYPE here.  (Meteor sets <!DOCTYPE html> for you)
node_modules/meteorite/node_modules/prompt/node_modules/utile/node_modules/mkdirp/bin/cmd.js:1:15: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
node_modules/meteorite/node_modules/prompt/node_modules/utile/node_modules/rimraf/bin.js:1:15: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
node_modules/meteorite/node_modules/fstream/node_modules/mkdirp/bin/cmd.js:1:15: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
node_modules/meteorite/node_modules/fstream/node_modules/rimraf/bin.js:1:15: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
node_modules/meteorite/node_modules/optimist/test/_/argv.js:1:15: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
node_modules/meteorite/node_modules/optimist/test/_/bin.js:1:15: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
node_modules/meteorite/node_modules/optimist/example/bool.js:1:15: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
node_modules/meteorite/node_modules/optimist/example/boolean_double.js:1:15: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
node_modules/meteorite/node_modules/optimist/example/boolean_single.js:1:15: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
node_modules/meteorite/node_modules/optimist/example/default_hash.js:1:15: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
node_modules/meteorite/node_modules/optimist/example/default_singles.js:1:15: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
node_modules/meteorite/node_modules/optimist/example/divide.js:1:15: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
node_modules/meteorite/node_modules/optimist/example/line_count.js:1:15: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
node_modules/meteorite/node_modules/optimist/example/line_count_options.js:1:15: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
node_modules/meteorite/node_modules/optimist/example/line_count_wrap.js:1:15: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
node_modules/meteorite/node_modules/optimist/example/nonopt.js:1:15: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
node_modules/meteorite/node_modules/optimist/example/reflect.js:1:15: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
node_modules/meteorite/node_modules/optimist/example/short.js:1:15: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
node_modules/meteorite/node_modules/optimist/example/string.js:1:15: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
node_modules/meteorite/node_modules/optimist/example/xup.js:1:15: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
node_modules/meteorite/bin/mrt.js:1:15: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

=> Your application has errors. Waiting for file change.
```

Another forum suggested running **mrt** which gives the same error so I run **sudo mrt** which starts out more promising, but still delivers an error at the end:

```
Stand back while Meteorite does its thing
✓ momentjs
    tag: https://github.com/crapthings/meteor-momentjs.git#v2.1.0.2
✓ crypto-base
    tag: https://github.com/oortcloud/meteor-crypto-base.git#v3.1.2.1
✓ crypto-md5
    tag: https://github.com/oortcloud/meteor-crypto-md5.git#v3.1.2.2
✓ iron-router
    tag: https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router.git#v0.8.2
✓ fast-render
    tag: https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-fast-render.git#v1.0.0
✓ spin
    tag: https://github.com/SachaG/meteor-spin.git#v2.0.4
✓ autoform
    tag: https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform.git#v0.16.1
✓ jquery-hotkeys
    tag: https://github.com/terryschen/meteor-jquery-hotkeys.git#v0.0.1
✓ marked
    tag: https://github.com/chuangbo/meteor-marked.git#v0.3.3
✓ bootstrap3-datepicker
    tag: https://github.com/rajit/bootstrap3-datepicker.git#v0.2.1
✓ subs-manager
    tag: https://github.com/meteorhacks/subs-manager.git#v1.0.2
✓ telescope-module-embedly
    tag: https://github.com/TelescopeJS/telescope-module-embedly.git#v0.2.6
✓ handlebars-server
    tag: https://github.com/EventedMind/meteor-handlebars-server.git#v1.2.0
✓ npm
    tag: https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-npm.git#v0.2.6
✓ mailchimp
    tag: https://github.com/MiroHibler/meteor-mailchimp.git#v0.4.2
✓ synced-cron
    tag: https://github.com/percolatestudio/meteor-synced-cron.git#v0.1.1
✓ cookies
    tag: https://github.com/subhog/meteor-cookies.git#v0.3.0
✓ telescope-newsletter
    tag: https://github.com/TelescopeJS/telescope-newsletter.git#v0.1.8
✓ accounts-entry
    tag: https://github.com/Differential/accounts-entry.git#v0.8.0
✓ iron-layout
    tag: https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-layout.git#v0.2.0
✓ simple-schema
    tag: https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-simple-schema.git#v0.7.0
✓ collection2
    tag: https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-collection2.git#v0.4.6
✓ moment
    tag: https://github.com/acreeger/meteor-moment.git#v2.6.0
✓ accounts-t9n
    tag: https://github.com/softwarerero/meteor-accounts-t9n.git#v0.0.5
✓ simple-form
    tag: https://github.com/Differential/simple-form.git#v0.1.8
✓ blaze-layout
    tag: https://github.com/EventedMind/blaze-layout.git#v0.2.5
✓ iron-core
    tag: https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-core.git#v0.2.0
✓ iron-dynamic-template
    tag: https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-dynamic-template.git#v0.2.1
✓ underscore-string-latest
    tag: https://github.com/TimHeckel/meteor-underscore-string.git#v2.3.3

Done installing smart packages

Ok, everything's ready. Here comes Meteor!

[[[[[ /home/me/Telescope ]]]]]

=> Started proxy.
=> Started MongoDB.     
iron-router: updating npm dependencies -- connect...
fast-render: updating npm dependencies -- connect...
spin: updating npm dependencies -- spin.js...
simple-schema: updating npm dependencies -- string...
handlebars-server: updating npm dependencies -- handlebars...
npm: updating npm dependencies -- juice, html-to-text...
sh: 1: node-gyp: Permission denied
npm ERR! error rolling back Error: ENOTEMPTY, rmdir '/root/.meteorite/packages/npm/arunoda/meteor-npm/177ab6118de5bf8cffb19481343d5762ff7a2aaf/.npm/package-new-15pys5v/node_modules/juice/node_modules/jsdom/node_modules/cssstyle/lib/properties'
npm ERR! error rolling back  jsdom@0.6.5 { [Error: ENOTEMPTY, rmdir '/root/.meteorite/packages/npm/arunoda/meteor-npm/177ab6118de5bf8cffb19481343d5762ff7a2aaf/.npm/package-new-15pys5v/node_modules/juice/node_modules/jsdom/node_modules/cssstyle/lib/properties']
npm ERR! error rolling back   errno: 53,
npm ERR! error rolling back   code: 'ENOTEMPTY',
npm ERR! error rolling back   path: '/root/.meteorite/packages/npm/arunoda/meteor-npm/177ab6118de5bf8cffb19481343d5762ff7a2aaf/.npm/package-new-15pys5v/node_modules/juice/node_modules/jsdom/node_modules/cssstyle/lib/properties' }
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, lstat '/root/.meteorite/packages/npm/arunoda/meteor-npm/177ab6118de5bf8cffb19481343d5762ff7a2aaf/.npm/package-new-15pys5v/node_modules/juice/node_modules/jsdom/node_modules/request/node_modules/hawk/Makefile'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! System Linux 3.2.0-4-amd64
npm ERR! command "/root/.meteor/tools/cef2bcd356/bin/node" "/root/.meteor/tools/cef2bcd356/bin/npm" "install" "juice@0.4.0"
npm ERR! cwd /root/.meteorite/packages/npm/arunoda/meteor-npm/177ab6118de5bf8cffb19481343d5762ff7a2aaf/.npm/package-new-15pys5v
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.29
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.14
npm ERR! path /root/.meteorite/packages/npm/arunoda/meteor-npm/177ab6118de5bf8cffb19481343d5762ff7a2aaf/.npm/package-new-15pys5v/node_modules/juice/node_modules/jsdom/node_modules/request/node_modules/hawk/Makefile
npm ERR! fstream_path /root/.meteorite/packages/npm/arunoda/meteor-npm/177ab6118de5bf8cffb19481343d5762ff7a2aaf/.npm/package-new-15pys5v/node_modules/juice/node_modules/jsdom/node_modules/request/node_modules/hawk/Makefile
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! fstream_stack /root/.meteor/tools/cef2bcd356/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/writer.js:284:26
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, lstat '/root/.meteorite/packages/npm/arunoda/meteor-npm/177ab6118de5bf8cffb19481343d5762ff7a2aaf/.npm/package-new-15pys5v/node_modules/juice/node_modules/jsdom/node_modules/htmlparser2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! System Linux 3.2.0-4-amd64
npm ERR! command "/root/.meteor/tools/cef2bcd356/bin/node" "/root/.meteor/tools/cef2bcd356/bin/npm" "install" "juice@0.4.0"
npm ERR! cwd /root/.meteorite/packages/npm/arunoda/meteor-npm/177ab6118de5bf8cffb19481343d5762ff7a2aaf/.npm/package-new-15pys5v
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.29
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.14
npm ERR! path /root/.meteorite/packages/npm/arunoda/meteor-npm/177ab6118de5bf8cffb19481343d5762ff7a2aaf/.npm/package-new-15pys5v/node_modules/juice/node_modules/jsdom/node_modules/htmlparser2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js
npm ERR! fstream_path /root/.meteorite/packages/npm/arunoda/meteor-npm/177ab6118de5bf8cffb19481343d5762ff7a2aaf/.npm/package-new-15pys5v/node_modules/juice/node_modules/jsdom/node_modules/htmlparser2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! fstream_stack /root/.meteor/tools/cef2bcd356/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/writer.js:284:26
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, lstat '/root/.meteorite/packages/npm/arunoda/meteor-npm/177ab6118de5bf8cffb19481343d5762ff7a2aaf/.npm/package-new-15pys5v/node_modules/juice/node_modules/jsdom/node_modules/request/node_modules/tough-cookie/lib/cookie.js'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! System Linux 3.2.0-4-amd64
npm ERR! command "/root/.meteor/tools/cef2bcd356/bin/node" "/root/.meteor/tools/cef2bcd356/bin/npm" "install" "juice@0.4.0"
npm ERR! cwd /root/.meteorite/packages/npm/arunoda/meteor-npm/177ab6118de5bf8cffb19481343d5762ff7a2aaf/.npm/package-new-15pys5v
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.29
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.14
npm ERR! path /root/.meteorite/packages/npm/arunoda/meteor-npm/177ab6118de5bf8cffb19481343d5762ff7a2aaf/.npm/package-new-15pys5v/node_modules/juice/node_modules/jsdom/node_modules/request/node_modules/tough-cookie/lib/cookie.js
npm ERR! fstream_path /root/.meteorite/packages/npm/arunoda/meteor-npm/177ab6118de5bf8cffb19481343d5762ff7a2aaf/.npm/package-new-15pys5v/node_modules/juice/node_modules/jsdom/node_modules/request/node_modules/tough-cookie/lib/cookie.js
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! fstream_stack /root/.meteor/tools/cef2bcd356/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/writer.js:284:26
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! error rolling back Error: ENOTEMPTY, rmdir '/root/.meteorite/packages/npm/arunoda/meteor-npm/177ab6118de5bf8cffb19481343d5762ff7a2aaf/.npm/package-new-15pys5v/node_modules/juice/node_modules/jsdom/node_modules/cssstyle/lib/properties'
npm ERR! error rolling back  juice@0.4.0 { [Error: ENOTEMPTY, rmdir '/root/.meteorite/packages/npm/arunoda/meteor-npm/177ab6118de5bf8cffb19481343d5762ff7a2aaf/.npm/package-new-15pys5v/node_modules/juice/node_modules/jsdom/node_modules/cssstyle/lib/properties']
npm ERR! error rolling back   errno: 53,
npm ERR! error rolling back   code: 'ENOTEMPTY',
npm ERR! error rolling back   path: '/root/.meteorite/packages/npm/arunoda/meteor-npm/177ab6118de5bf8cffb19481343d5762ff7a2aaf/.npm/package-new-15pys5v/node_modules/juice/node_modules/jsdom/node_modules/cssstyle/lib/properties' }
npm ERR! contextify@0.1.8 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 127
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the contextify@0.1.8 install script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the contextify package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls contextify
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! System Linux 3.2.0-4-amd64
npm ERR! command "/root/.meteor/tools/cef2bcd356/bin/node" "/root/.meteor/tools/cef2bcd356/bin/npm" "install" "juice@0.4.0"
npm ERR! cwd /root/.meteorite/packages/npm/arunoda/meteor-npm/177ab6118de5bf8cffb19481343d5762ff7a2aaf/.npm/package-new-15pys5v
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.29
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.14
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.meteorite/packages/npm/arunoda/meteor-npm/177ab6118de5bf8cffb19481343d5762ff7a2aaf/.npm/package-new-15pys5v/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0

mailchimp: updating npm dependencies -- mailchimp...
synced-cron: updating npm dependencies -- later...
telescope-newsletter: updating npm dependencies -- later...
=> Errors prevented startup:

While building the application:
node_modules/meteorite/node_modules/prompt/node_modules/winston/node_modules/pkginfo/docs/pkginfo.html:1: Can't set DOCTYPE here.  (Meteor sets <!DOCTYPE html> for you)
node_modules/meteorite/node_modules/ddp/node_modules/meteor-ejson/node_modules/underscore/index.html:1: Can't set DOCTYPE here.  (Meteor sets <!DOCTYPE html> for you)
node_modules/meteorite/node_modules/ddp/node_modules/node-srp/node_modules/underscore/index.html:1: Can't set DOCTYPE here.  (Meteor sets <!DOCTYPE html> for you)
node_modules/meteorite/node_modules/ddp/node_modules/faye-websocket/examples/sse.html:1: Can't set DOCTYPE here.  (Meteor sets <!DOCTYPE html> for you)
node_modules/meteorite/node_modules/ddp/node_modules/faye-websocket/examples/ws.html:1: Can't set DOCTYPE here.  (Meteor sets <!DOCTYPE html> for you)
node_modules/meteorite/node_modules/prompt/node_modules/pkginfo/docs/pkginfo.html:1: Can't set DOCTYPE here.  (Meteor sets <!DOCTYPE html> for you)
node_modules/meteorite/node_modules/prompt/docs/prompt.html:1: Can't set DOCTYPE here.  (Meteor sets <!DOCTYPE html> for you)
node_modules/meteorite/node_modules/colors/example.html:1: Can't set DOCTYPE here.  (Meteor sets <!DOCTYPE html> for you)
node_modules/meteorite/node_modules/underscore/index.html:1: Can't set DOCTYPE here.  (Meteor sets <!DOCTYPE html> for you)
node_modules/meteorite/node_modules/prompt/node_modules/utile/node_modules/mkdirp/bin/cmd.js:1:15: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
node_modules/meteorite/node_modules/prompt/node_modules/utile/node_modules/rimraf/bin.js:1:15: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
node_modules/meteorite/node_modules/fstream/node_modules/mkdirp/bin/cmd.js:1:15: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
node_modules/meteorite/node_modules/fstream/node_modules/rimraf/bin.js:1:15: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
node_modules/meteorite/node_modules/optimist/test/_/argv.js:1:15: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
node_modules/meteorite/node_modules/optimist/test/_/bin.js:1:15: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
node_modules/meteorite/node_modules/optimist/example/bool.js:1:15: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
node_modules/meteorite/node_modules/optimist/example/boolean_double.js:1:15: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
node_modules/meteorite/node_modules/optimist/example/boolean_single.js:1:15: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
node_modules/meteorite/node_modules/optimist/example/default_hash.js:1:15: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
node_modules/meteorite/node_modules/optimist/example/default_singles.js:1:15: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
node_modules/meteorite/node_modules/optimist/example/divide.js:1:15: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
node_modules/meteorite/node_modules/optimist/example/line_count.js:1:15: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
node_modules/meteorite/node_modules/optimist/example/line_count_options.js:1:15: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
node_modules/meteorite/node_modules/optimist/example/line_count_wrap.js:1:15: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
node_modules/meteorite/node_modules/optimist/example/nonopt.js:1:15: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
node_modules/meteorite/node_modules/optimist/example/reflect.js:1:15: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
node_modules/meteorite/node_modules/optimist/example/short.js:1:15: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
node_modules/meteorite/node_modules/optimist/example/string.js:1:15: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
node_modules/meteorite/node_modules/optimist/example/xup.js:1:15: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
node_modules/meteorite/bin/mrt.js:1:15: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

While building package `npm`:
error: couldn't install npm package

=> Your application has errors. Waiting for file change.
```

The thing is, when I tried to install NPM, it wouldn't let me do it without using `sudo` so I did `sudo -H npm install -g meteorite` though I think the first time I left out the -H so then I tried to wipe clean and start fresh:

```
sudo mrt uninstall
sudo mrt uninstall --system
rm -rf ~/.meteorite

sudo rm /usr/local/bin/meteor
rm -rf ~/.meteor
```

now I still cd into Telescope and hit mrt but get this error:

```
[[[[[ ~/Telescope ]]]]]

=> Started proxy.
=> Started MongoDB.     
iron-router: updating npm dependencies -- connect...
fast-render: updating npm dependencies -- connect...
spin: updating npm dependencies -- spin.js...
simple-schema: updating npm dependencies -- string...
handlebars-server: updating npm dependencies -- handlebars...
npm: updating npm dependencies -- juice, html-to-text...
mailchimp: updating npm dependencies -- mailchimp...
synced-cron: updating npm dependencies -- later...
telescope-newsletter: updating npm dependencies -- later...

/home/me/.meteor/tools/cef2bcd356/lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:173
                        throw(ex);
                              ^
Error: EACCES, permission denied '/home/me/Telescope/.meteor/local/build-garbage-xd2tqb/README'
  at Object.fs.unlinkSync (fs.js:765:18)
  at Object.files.rm_recursive (/home/me/.meteor/tools/cef2bcd356/tools/files.js:219:8)
  at /home/me/.meteor/tools/cef2bcd356/tools/files.js:215:13
  at Array.forEach (native)
  at Function._.each._.forEach (/home/me/.meteor/tools/cef2bcd356/lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
  at Object.files.rm_recursive (/home/me/.meteor/tools/cef2bcd356/tools/files.js:213:7)
  at Object.files.renameDirAlmostAtomically (/home/me/.meteor/tools/cef2bcd356/tools/files.js:456:11)
  at [object Object]._.extend.complete (/home/me/.meteor/tools/cef2bcd356/tools/builder.js:438:11)
  at writeSiteArchive (/home/me/.meteor/tools/cef2bcd356/tools/bundler.js:1580:13)
  at /home/me/.meteor/tools/cef2bcd356/tools/bundler.js:1897:18
  at Object.capture (/home/me/.meteor/tools/cef2bcd356/tools/buildmessage.js:191:5)
  at Object.exports.bundle (/home/me/.meteor/tools/cef2bcd356/tools/bundler.js:1667:31)
  at [object Object]._.extend._runOnce (/home/me/.meteor/tools/cef2bcd356/tools/run-app.js:406:32)
  at [object Object]._.extend._fiber (/home/me/.meteor/tools/cef2bcd356/tools/run-app.js:540:28)
  at /home/me/.meteor/tools/cef2bcd356/tools/run-app.js:348:12


/usr/lib/node_modules/meteorite/lib/command.js:41
            throw "Command exited with " + code + "/" + signal;
                                                      ^
Command exited with 8/
```

I **really** need to get this to work, can anyone please help me? Thank you kindly! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you ran a command as root that you shouldn't have and botched your file permissions a little.  You could always safely clear that up in your home dir with:

`sudo chown -R me /home/me`

(assuming your non-root user name is "me", as is indicated in your error)

That will recursively set "me" as the owner of every file in /home/me/.  You can optionally do the same for your global node_modules with:

`sudo chown -R me /PATH/TO/GLOBAL/node_modules`

(More on npm folder locations for whatever OS you have [here](https://www.npmjs.org/doc/files/npm-folders.html))

That should allow you to install global node module with: `npm install -g SOMETHING` without requiring sudo.  Note that there is a lot of debate around whether that is a security risk.  Do a Google search for "node_modules permissions" and you'll find tons of passionate debates on the topic.  For me, I have been owning that dir with my regular user for years without incident. So do a little research and decide what sits best with you.  Worst case, you'd just have to do `sudo npm install -g SOMETHING`.  Not really a big deal.  But I prefer not to have to sudo.  That way I can do global or local modules with the same user and only include/exclude the -g flag in the command.  Make sense?

And as far as I know, there is never a good reason to run `sudo` for `mrt` or `meteor`.  When you do, it is putting files in root's home dir at `/root/.meteorite/` and `/root/.meteor/` (with root as the owner, of course) and not in the home dir of the user you are currently logged in as (in your case, `/home/me/.meteorite/` and `/home/me/.meteor/`).

When you add a smart package to a meteor app with `mrt add SOMETHING`, it is not actually putting the files in your app directory.  It is symlinking them to the `~/.meteorite/packages`.  That way you don't download a new copy for every app you use that package in.  But when you `sudo mrt add SOMETHING`, it's downloading and symlinking to `/root/.meteorite/packages` instead.  That's obviously an unnecessary permissions nightmare.

You may want to `sudo rm -rf /root/.meteor /root/.meteorite` too.  There's no reason to have that stuff there if you don't normally develop as root.  Everything with meteor and meteorite should be safely operating from `/home/me/`.

Hope this clears it up a little.

Comment: Appears to have worked! You are a life saver my friend! I was able to deploy to modulus, so we'll see how it goes (excited). Next step is figuring out how to keep my installation secure and up to date :)

Comment: Glad to hear I helped.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You've installed meteorite as a local node module. You shouldn't do this.

Just remove your `node_modules` directory. If everything else is installed correctly, your app should then work.

Meteor grabs all .js and .html files in your project directory and treats them as project files. A few conventions are required in order for those files to compile properly. Node modules usually don't conform to such conventions, so placing them in `node_modules` folder inside project dir causes a compilation error.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I deleted node_modules directory but still no dice.

running `meteor` gives a long permissions error `Error: EACCES, permission denied '/home/me/Telescope/packages/accounts-entry'
    at Object.fs.statSync (fs.js:689:18)...` and running `sudo mrt` gives me a long permissions error `sh: 1: node-gyp: Permission denied
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, lstat '/root/.meteorite/packages/npm/arunoda/meteor-npm/177ab6118de5bf8cffb19481343d5762ff7a2aaf/.npm/package-new-1xv8nrl/node_modules/juice/node_modules/jsdom/node_modules/cssstyle/lib/properties/webkitColumnRuleStyle.js'

Comment: sorry I'm trying to figure out the proper conventions for using StackExchange, I have a character limit in these comments so I can't paste the full error.

I did try this command to fix the NPM permissions error `sudo chown -R `whoami` ~/.npm` but it didn't seem to help

Answer (score 0):

There is a script to easy install Telescope with meteor:

Install: $ `curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/AndreasPrang/TelescopeJS-Install/master/install.sh | sh`

http://andreasprang.de/2014/09/08/how-to-install-script-telescopejs-for-debian-ubuntu/